# Get the ID of each visible image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got 21 images loaded dynamically into multiple divs. Below is an example of the images.

```
<img src="fruits/lychee.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl156">
<img src="fruits/cranberry.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl141">
<img src="fruits/avocado.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl214">
```

When the page loads 3 - 6 random images will be visible. I want to get the id of each image when `$('#findVisible')` is clicked. This is my code but It doesn't alert the id? How can I get the ID of each visible image?

```
$('#findVisible').click(function(){
     if ($('.fruit:visible').length > 0) {
        //dosomething
        $('.fruit:visible').each(function(){
             var g = $(this.id);
             alert(g) //DOES NOT WORK?
        });      
        return false;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` wrapping from `$(this.id)`

```js
$('#findVisible').click(function() {
  if ($('.fruit:visible').length > 0) {
    //dosomething
    $('.fruit:visible').each(function() {
      var g = this.id;
      alert(g) //DOES NOT WORK?
    });
    return false; //to stop refreshing the page
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="fruits/lychee.png" class="fruit" id="fruitl156">
<img src="fruits/cranberry.png" class="fruit" id="fruitl141">
<img src="fruits/avocado.png" class="fruit" id="fruitl214">
<button id="findVisible">click</button>
```

Comment: @Bekki : glad to help :)